# Is “should” sometimes ambiguous between “if” and “ought to”?

Tags: grammar, ambiguity, semantics

I know that nowadays in American informal English “should” almost always means “ought to”, as in “I should treat my family well”, but that it can also mean “if” or “in the event that”, as in “Should you come, I will treat you well”.

Question: are there constructions in which “should” is semantically ambiguous between these two meanings?

Thank you!

Comment: No, because I should and should you [if] are different structures.

Comment: Offhand I'd say there's ***zero*** chance  of there being an "utterance" where it's ambiguous whether ***should*** means ***if*** or ***ought to***, because they're completely different "parts of speech". But even if you could contrive some *written* context where two different parsings seemed possible, I'm sure the text wouldn't still be ambiguous in its *spoken* form. Ambiguity that only applies to written forms isn't really ambiguity anyway - it's just "poor quality writing style" (if the ambiguity is "real").

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks! I’m mainly concerned with written English, as I write technical stuff while not being a native speaker. I’m trying to guard against that poor writing.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we only welcome "questions based on actual problems that you face." This one looks more like an "intellectual game".

Comment: I don't think it's zero chance; if you include subordinate clauses, ellipses, and other complexities, there's almost always some construction that would be ambiguous, but if you write a straightforward "you should do X" then that's going to be unambiguous. (Note that it's not just shall: [must](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/must) and most other modals have multiple meanings - "You must do this" vs "You must have done this", while "can" can mean permission or possibility - and it's not a big problem.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Not at all, I have faced the problem of fearing ambiguity many times.

Comment: @StuartF:  In the *written* form, *You must be Dr Livingstone* is ambiguous. Rather than being something Stanley said when he met Livingstone, it could be a movie casting director telling some actor that he can't choose to play Stanley because he's already been cast as Livingstone. But no such ambiguity could exist in the real world.

Comment: @user354948: If you're particularly focused on American English, you may wish to know that ***nowadays*** is [far less common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=know+that+nowadays%3Aeng_us_2019%2Cknow+that+nowadays%3Aeng_gb_2019&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=50) in Ame than in BrE.

Comment: Don't use *should for if* in technical writing. Use if or in the event of. In the event of fire, press the button. If a fire breaks out, press the button. [People in the states use nowadays all the time. Be aware that with such a large population, comparisons with "like BrE speakers" is well nigh impossible.

Comment: ...also note [this usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=If+that+should+happen%3Aeng_us_2019%2CIf+that+should+happen%3Aeng_gb_2019&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=50) showing that *If that **should** happen* is about equally common in BrE and AmE (it's simply *not true* that AmE is different to BrE in this respect).

Comment: @Lambie Why shouldn’t I use it in technical writing?

Comment: Read all of these: In the event of a fire, press the button. If a fire breaks out, press the button. Should a fire break out, evacuate immediately.  The point is one should try and stick to: [when, if, null set) subject verb object or predicate, Should x occur is just not simple and could be misunderstood by some people. And could be considered the wrong register, literary or wordy: https://gato-docs.its.txst.edu/slac/Subject/Writing/Technical-Writing/Technical-Writing--What-to-Avoid/Technical

Answer (score 3):

It's conceivable, but very unlikely, because it would require a context in which a single clause could stand either as a question (which normally stands alone), or as the protasis of a conditional (which normally doesn't).

An isolated protasis can occur in conversation -  "Can he come and see you?" "**If he needs to.**" But few people would say "Should he need to" in that sense, because inverted conditional like that are now rather formal.

And even if somebody did say "Should he need to" in that context, the intonation will be different from if they were asking "Should he need to?"

Comment: I can't help wondering if it's possible for HRT (rising intonation)  in "Valley-speak / Aussie English" to create ambiguity with *Can he come and see you? **Should he need to?*** I mean can it be ambiguous whether that's ***...in the event that** he needs to see you,* or just the speaker wondering whether "he" could or should have any need to see the addressee (regardless of whether he's *permitted* to do so).

Comment: Another possibility: "Should you finish work early, might we buy something for lunch, may we see a movie later, and could they bring us some coffee?" It could be read either as four questions or as a protasis followed by three questions. I'm sure that better examples could be contrived, but in any case it would certainly be rare.

Comment: @ColinFine In your example the differentiation wouldn’t just be made in speech, but also in writing, by the question mark.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, good example, I can hear it in my mind!

Comment: @MarcInManhattan That took some invention, haha!

Comment: @ColinFine Just discovered that a protasis is what we logicians call an antecedent (except that the “if” is not part of an antecedent in logic).

Comment: @user354948 Yes, and the fact that it did suggests that you probably shouldn't worry much about it, as Colin Fine says.